# How to access inherited class attribute from a third class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

The goal of the code structure below is to be able to store pointers to objects of any class inherited from **'A'**.

When I run this code, I get 0 written out, but what I'm trying to access is the **'B' object**'s 'num' value, which is 1. How can I do that?

As far as I know, when you create an inherited class's object, you create an object of the parent class too automatically. So can I somehow access the parent class object from it's child and set it's class member to match?

See minimal reproducible example below.

**Update: Virtual functions solved the problem.**

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int num;

    A()
    {
        num = 0;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int num;

    B()
    {
        num = 1;
    }
};

class C 
{
public:
    A* ptr_array[2];

    C()
    {
        ptr_array[0] = new B();
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << ptr_array[0]->num << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C* object_c = new C();
    object_c->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: c++ has attributes but I suppose you are talking about class members. Instead of describing the code you should show the code

Comment: when you have an array of pointers, bad things may well happen. Show your code.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I did my best to fix the problems.

Comment: If your `C` class needs to access an attribute of `B` it should have a `B *`, not an `A *`. It's that simple. No magic words like "inheritance" help here.  Inheritance helps when you decide that `C` should not access anything from `B` or know about `B` at all, but still work correctly when its pointer to `A` points to a `B`. This is achieved with virtual functions defined in `A` and then overridden in `B`. Until then, you are not using inheritance, you are misusing it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: I disagree. One can access the attributes of a derived class by means of a pointer to the base class, and it's a very useful technique. That's the point of object-oriented languages (and I think it might even be part of the definition of object-orientation, I'll have to look it up).

Comment: @Beta No, the point of, and some (myself including) say the *definition* of, object-oriented programming is using *late binding* (in C++-specific terms, virtual functions). The only way you can directly access the attributes of a derived class by means of a pointer to the base class is by casting, and that's just the exact opposite of object-oriented programming.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That's a very sly introduction of the word *"directly".*

Comment: @Beta That's for clarity. I guess I could have omitted it, and then get pointless comments about how you can access attributes by calling functions.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Or you could have used it earlier, and prevented a lot of pointless misunderstanding.

Comment: @Beta I am under no contractual obligation to produce only perfectly worded comments that are understood equally by all people from all backgrounds exactly how I intend them to be understood. Sorry about the inconvenience this causes.

Comment: My goal is polymorphism for classes inherited from A. So which approach should I read into, casting or virtual functions? Or both?

Comment: @Joblivion: Definitely virtual functions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is a red herring. You are only using one pointer. Might just as well have it as a member for the sake of the example.

I suppose you might need something like this (note, untested code).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    A() : m_num(0) {} // use this instead of assignment in the c'tor body

    virtual int getNum() { return m_num; } // this is **the** way to use inheritance

    virtual ~A() = default; // required
  private:
    int m_num;
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    B() : m_otherNum(1) {}

    virtual int getNum() { return m_otherNum; } // does something different from A
  private:
    int m_otherNum; // you could also call it m_num, but for clarity I use a different name 
};

class C {
  public:
    C() : m_a (std::make_unique<B>()) {} // note, use this instead of new B

    void print() {
      std::cout << m_a->getNum() << std::endl;
    }

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> m_a; // note, use this instead of A* m_a;
};
```

I have no way of knowing if this is really what you need (or you think you need). This is how inheritance is supposed to be used in object-oriented programming. You can use it in various other ways and produce correct (as far as the language definition is concerned) programs. But if this is the case, then (public) inheritance is likely not the best tool for the job.

Comment: Seeing the confusion in the comments, I should have been more precise about my purpose. My goal is to achieve polymorphism among classes derived from A. The reason C has an array of pointers, is to have many different class objects (ptr-s to them), which are all derived from class A. Btw I appreciate the extra suggestions, I'll look into those language elements!

Comment: Polymorphism in C++ is synonymous with virtual functions. (There are other kinds, but as far as inheritance goes, this is the only kind.) I must warn you against meaningless usage of the word "polymorphism" . Polymorphism is a tool, not a goal. What is your goal?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you define a member `num` in `A`, and *another* member `num` in `B`. So an object of type `B` has *two* members called `num`, and you're leaving it to the compiler to choose which one to use -- which it does, according to logical rules which may be unfamiliar to you.

If you remove the line `in num;` from the definition of `B`, the code will work as you intend.

Comment: But then it's not a derived class attribute, it's a base class attribute. You just set its value from the derived class I have no idea whether this is what OP wants. One could have set it from elsewhere, e.g. `ptr_array[0]->num = 42;` A derived class is not needed for this.

Comment: Unfortunately int num of B is the point of the whole thing, that's what I'm trying to access. There are several classes like B, derived from A, and I'd like to put them into one array.

Comment: @Joblivion: This is starting to look like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there a good reason to have a member in `A` and another in `B` *with the same name?* If not, then you're going out of your way to make the problem obscure and confusing.